# Adding another monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to add a another monitor to my PC (Dell 3010 with 2GB, i3 processor), will I need to update my PC first?  I am getting a Dell 22" Model 2217H monitor, what type of cable I will need to setup a dual monitor.

Comment: How many monitors do you currently have and what cables are they connected with? Are there any other available video connectors on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

The Dell 3010 comes with an AMD Radeon HD 7470 graphics card, which includes 3 video outputs: DVI, DisplayPort, and VGA.

You will need to look at the back of your computer and see which of the ports are open and purchase an appropriate cable, and make sure the monitor you want to purchase has this same connector.